# C++ issue with 2D vector: When executed, your code modified memory in a way that was illegal

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

this is my first time posting a question in SO. I've been working in a program that tests if there are four consecutive numbers of the same value. I am using Visual Studio as my IDE and my code is compiling good, the problem is that in my class, we are posting the code through a website (Pearson) which tests if the code is correct or not. The problem that is giving me is the following: "When executed, your code modified memory in a way that was illegal. Common causes for this problem include array indexing errors and pointer operation (*) errors." My understanding of pointers is very low, but I don't see anything wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int  row = 6;
int col = 7;

bool checkRow(vector<vector<int>> v) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++) {
            if (a[i][j - 1] == a[i][j]) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            } if (count == 3) {
                return true;
            }
        } count = 0;
    } return false;
}

bool checkCol(vector<vector<int>> v) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++) {
            if (a[j - 1][i] == a[j][i]) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            } if (count == 3) {
                return true;
            }
        } count = 0;
    } return false;
}

bool diagonalOne(vector<vector<int>> v) {
    int count = 0;
    if (row < 4 || col < 4) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (int k = 3; k < col; k++) {
            for (int i = 1, j = k; j > 0; i++, j--) {
                if (a[i][j - 1] == a[i - 1][j]) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    count = 0;
                } if (count == 3) {
                    return true;
                }
            } count = 0;
        }
        int i = 1;
        int j = row - 1;
        int k = 0;
        count = 0;

        for(int i = 1; row - i > 3; i++){
            k = i;
            for (j = col - 1; j - 1 > i; j--, k++) {
                if (a[k][j] == a[k + 1][j - 1]) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    count = 0;
                } if (count == 3) {
                    return true;
                } 
            } count = 0;
        } return false;
    } 
}

bool diagonalTwo(vector<vector<int>> v) {
    int count = 0;
    int i, j, k;

    if (row < 4 || col > 4) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 1; i < col - i; i++) {
            k = 0;
            for (j = i; j < row; j++, k++) {
                if (a[k][j] == a[k + 1][j + 1]) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    count = 0;
                } if (count == 3) {
                    return true;
                }
            } count = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < row - 3; i++) {
                k = i;
                for (j = 0; j + 1 < row - i; j++, k++) {
                    if (a[k][j] == a[k + 1][j + 1]) {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else {
                        count = 0;
                    } if (count == 3) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
            } cout << endl;
            count = 0;
        } return false;
    }
}

bool isConsecutiveFour(vector<vector<int>> & values) {
    if (checkRow(values) == true) {
        return true;
    } if (checkCol(values) == true) {
        return true;
    } if (diagonalOne(values) == true) {
        return true;
    } if (diagonalTwo(values) == true) {
        return true;
    } return false;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;


    vector<vector<int>>a(row);
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        a[i] = vector<int>(col);
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        } cout << endl;
    }

    if (isConsecutiveFour(a) == true) {
        cout << "The array has consecutive fours" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The array does not have consecutive fours" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: First observation: this is not the code that causes the invalid memory access, because it doesn't compile. Did you confuse the unused `v` with the non-existent `a`? (There is an `a` in `main`, but in all the functions there is only a `v`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounds on the loops inside your `checkCol` function are wrong, that's why a segmentation fault is occurring. Make it :

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < row; j++) {
```

Same error is with `diagonalOne` function. Make it :

```cpp
  for (int k = 3; k < row; k++) {
```

*Advice :* Avoid using `using namespace std` and `system("PAUSE")`, and make yourself familiar with debugger present in VS.